# ggnested relative abundance graph error differing number of rows

Tags: r, ggplot2, phyloseq

I am trying to produce a ggnested relative abundance bar plot with two levels (Phylum and Family), I am following the tutorial for microeco (https://chiliubio.github.io/microeco_tutorial/composition-based-class.html#trans_abund-class). I've changed the code to fit my own data:

```
test1 <- trans_abund$new(dataset = dataset, taxrank = "Family", ntaxa = 10, high_level = "Phylum", prefix = "\\|")

test1$plot_bar(ggnested = TRUE, facet = c("coral_species", "compartment"), xtext_angle = 30)
```

The first line works but when I run the second line I keep getting the error:

```
Error in data.frame(group = groups, group_colour = clr_pal[1:n_clrs]) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 1
```

I have tried looking at the lengths of the different groups, and "Error: object 'clr_pal' not found", I've tried to add in my own colour palette too but this didn't work.

I have also checked my own groups (the taxonomy table, coral_species and compartments) all match up, and also aren't mentioned in the error?

I'm sure it's a simple fix I'm just very stuck! Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance from a very tired postgrad!

Comment: Hi Charlotte. It's much easier to help if you include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) so that we can test where the error comes from, and suggest solutions. Have you actually defined an object called `clr_pal` and another called `n_clrs`? Can you show use the output from `dput(dataset)`? Thanks

Comment: Hi Allen! Apologies, I'm not too entirely sure how to minimize the data set for an example, I have a microeco table/phyloseq object of the data? When I use dput(dataset) I just get: <environment>  No I haven't defined anything for clr_pal or n_clrs, which adds to why I am confused. Thank you!

Comment: Hi Charlotte, `dput()` generates a reproducible copy of your data. Try adding the name of the dataset you're starting with to the `dput()` function e.g. `dput(my_data)`. Thanks